# Google App Engine Java - Temporary Search Error (FTS)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-search

I receive for a lot of queries on my FTS  indexes this exception:

```
com.google.appengine.api.search.SearchException >> 
Temporary search service error
com.google.appengine.api.search.IndexImpl$4.convertException(IndexImpl.java:354)
com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:97)
com.google.appengine.api.search.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:73)
com.google.appengine.api.search.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:32)
com.google.appengine.api.search.IndexImpl.search(IndexImpl.java:505)
```

This error appears for some period of time for certain queries, then it works for that query, but fails for others.

Can you help me with this?
I can provide additional data on request!

Comment: Please add more info. What kind of app are deploying? What Google Cloud products are you using in order to deploy it. Try to give as many details as you can